# How do we Initialize a Hopfield Neural Network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have just started reading about neural networks and I have a basic question. Regarding "initializing" the Hopfield network, I am unable to understand that notion of initialization. That is, do we input some random numbers? or do input a well defined pattern which makes the neurons settle down first time up, assuming all neurons were at state equal to zero, with other stable states being either 1 or -1 after the input.

Consider the neural network below. Which I have taken from [HeatonResearch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnUI6PaHqCw&playnext=1&list=PLEF8715EA0FDB04AE)

Glad if someone clears this to me.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When initialising neural networks, including the recurrent Hopfield networks, it is common to initialise with random weights, as that in general will give good learning times over multiple trials and over an ensemble of runs, it will avoid local minima.  It is usually not a good idea to start from the same starting weights over multiple runs as you will likely encounter the same local minima.  With some configurations, the learning can be sped up by doing an analysis of the role of the node in the functional mapping, but that is often a later step in the analysis after getting something working.

Comment: Hopfield networks are zero-initialized, because they serve as content-addressable memory — they recall the data they have been trained on. As far as I can tell, this would not work well with random initialization.

Comment: @Don Reba: I'm not sure what you mean by pointing to it's use.  Yes, it's use is often as memory, for things it is trained on.  When it hasn't been trained, it doesn't mean it is correct to return the result of 0 initialised network, unless that has somehow been added as an additional requirement (which would be odd).  Most examples I have seen (as an example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/HopfieldNeuralNetwork.aspx) use random initialisation (see Neuron ctor) for the reason I gave (avoiding encountering the same minima).

Comment: Also see http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/329353 (line 31) which also creates a starting random weight matrix.  It is the standard solution to initialisation that I have seen many times over.  The only time I see something else is when specific analysis shows training can occur quicker with a different starting point, which occurs in things like two level feedback training networks with some standard response adjustments for training nonlinear function approximation.  Even then, I haven't seen 0 be the appropriate starting point...

Comment: @Don and ex0du5, so as far as I have seen this looks like we can still use a random weight matrix. But as ex0du5 points out that we can use a different starting point given that we know it gives off better results. Nevertheless, you answers clear a lot of doubt.

Comment: @ex0du5, fair enough. +1, then.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a Hopefiled network is to recall the data it has been shown, serving as content-addressable memory. It begins as a clean slate, with all weights set to zero. Training the network on a vector adjusts the weights to respond to it.

The output of a node in a Hopfield network depends on the state of each other node and the weight of the node's connection to it. States correspond to the input, with intput 0 mapping to -1, and the input 1 mapping to 1. So, if the network in your example had input 1010, N1 would have state 1, N2 -1, N3 1, and N4 -1.

Training the network means adding the dot product between the output and itself to the weight matrix setting the diagonal to zero. So, to train on 10101, we would add [1 -1 1 -1 ] · [1 -1 1 -1 ]ᵀ to the weight matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this repository --> [Hopfield Network](https://github.com/yogonza524/HopfieldNetwork)

There you have an example for test a pattern after train the Network off-line. This is the test

```
@Test
public void HopfieldTest(){
 double[] p1 = new double[]{1.0, -1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0};
 double[] p2 = new double[]{1.0, 1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0};
 double[] p3 = new double[]{1.0, 1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0};

 ArrayList<double[]> patterns = new ArrayList<>();
 patterns.add(p1);
 patterns.add(p2);

 Hopfield h = new Hopfield(9, new StepFunction());

 h.train(patterns); //train and load the Weight matrix

 double[] result = h.test(p3); //Test a pattern

 System.out.println("\nConnections of Network: " + h.connections() + "\n"); //show Neural connections
 System.out.println("Good recuperation capacity of samples: " + Hopfield.goodRecuperation(h.getWeights().length) + "\n");
 System.out.println("Perfect recuperation capacity of samples: " + 
 Hopfield.perfectRacuperation(h.getWeights().length) + "\n");
 System.out.println("Energy: " + h.energy(result));

 System.out.println("Weight Matrix");
 Matrix.showMatrix(h.getWeights());
 System.out.println("\nPattern result of test");
 Matrix.showVector(result);

 h.showAuxVector();
}
```

And after run the test you can see

```
Running HopfieldTest

Connections of Network: 72

Good recuperation capacity of samples: 1

Perfect recuperation capacity of samples: 1

Energy: -32.0

Weight Matrix
 0.0        0.0     2.0    -2.0      2.0       -2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
 0.0        0.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0      -2.0       2.0    -2.0
 2.0        0.0     0.0    -2.0      2.0       -2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
-2.0        0.0    -2.0     0.0     -2.0        2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
 2.0        0.0     2.0    -2.0      0.0       -2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
-2.0        0.0    -2.0     2.0     -2.0        0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
 0.0       -2.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0      -2.0     2.0
 0.0        2.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0      -2.0       0.0    -2.0
 0.0       -2.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0       2.0      -2.0     0.0

Pattern result of test 

1.0        1.0     1.0     -1.0     1.0       -1.0      -1.0       1.0     -1.0
-------------------------
The auxiliar vector is empty
```

I hope you find it useful. Regards